# Error al cargar DropDownList con valores correctos

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy desarrollando mi primer CRUD en mi aplicacion web utilizando ASP.NET MVC y estoy presentando un error al momento de cargar el DropDownList y es que no me esta cargando la información correcta que se tiene almacenada en la base de datos

El campo que se deberia cargar en el DropDownList, coloco en la tabla porque su nombre es muy largo

Al momento de darle Editar me muestra el formulario con todos los campos correctos menos el de DropDownList

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi estoy cargando los datos en el formulario al momento de editar,

**Controlador**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EditService(TK_CT_SERVICES service)
        {
            //Validamos si el modelo que entra es valido 
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return View();

            try
            {                
                using (var db = new dbGoldenTicket())
                {
                    TK_CT_SERVICES serv = db.TK_CT_SERVICES.Find(service);

                    if (serv != null)
                    {
                        serv.NAME = service.NAME;
                        serv.CONTENT = service.CONTENT;
                        serv.TK_CT_AREAS_ID = service.TK_CT_AREAS_ID;
                        serv.ENABLED = service.ENABLED;
                        serv.VISIBILITY = service.VISIBILITY;
                    }

                    db.SaveChanges();
                    //Despues de realizar un cambio al servicio
                    //redireccionamos al index (vista del catalogo de servicios)
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }               
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error al editar un servicio del catalogo, verifique la información nuevamente");
                return View();
            }
            
        }
```

**Vista**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TK_CT_AREAS_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.Action("ListArea")
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TK_CT_AREAS_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Esta es la funcion con la que cargo las areas

```
public ActionResult ListArea()
        {
            using (var db = new dbGoldenTicket())
            {
                return PartialView(db.TK_CT_AREAS.ToList());
            }
        }
```

**Vista parcial**

```
@model IEnumerable<GoldenTicket.Models.TK_CT_AREAS>


<select class="form-control" id="TK_CT_AREAS_ID" name="TK_CT_AREAS_ID">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <option value="@item.TK_CT_AREAS_ID">@item.NAME</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Cómo generas el DropDownMenu, Pudieras agregar la vista donde lo generas, por favor?

Comment: Utilizo Razor para ello y en el @Html.Action mando a llamar ListArea

Comment: Si, pero que código razor hay en esa vista parcial?

Comment: @KodiakMx revisa nuevamente la pregunta se actualizo con el codigo de la vista parcial

Comment: ya vi, gracias...

Comment: @KodiakMx encontraste alguna solución

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96931/discussion-between-sebastian-salazar-and-kodiakmx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo recomendaría cargar la lista de área en el `ViewBag`, y esa lista usarla para crear el select-option con el Html helper de `@Html.DropDownListFor`. Con esto incluso se evita usar la vista parcial que de estaba usando.

Lo que se necesitas hacer es,

en el **controlador** agregar la lista en el ViewBag, en este caso al espacio llamado *Areas*

```
public ActionResult EditService(string serviceId)
{
    using (var db = new dbGoldenTicket())
    {
        TK_CT_SERVICES cs = db.TK_CT_SERVICES.Find(serviceId);
        ViewBag.Areas = db.TK_CT_AREAS.ToList();
        return View(cs);
    }
}
```

y en la **vista** usar esa lista para crear un select-option con el *@Html.DropDownListFor*

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TK_CT_AREAS_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TK_CT_AREAS_ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Areas, "TK_CT_AREAS_ID", "NAME"), "-- Selecciona una opción --", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TK_CT_AREAS_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Nota, como el DropDownListFor ya tiene su propiedad de TK_CT_AREAS_ID con un valor, se seleccionará su respectivo valor por default. Pero si no fuera así, se puede marcar que se seleccione un valor poniéndole un cuarto parámetro al constructor de `SelectList`. Quedaría así:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TK_CT_AREAS_ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.Areas, "TK_CT_AREAS_ID", "NAME", Model.TK_CT_AREAS_ID), "-- Selecciona una opción --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Segun el codigo que tengo como lo puedo implementar ?